# bloomberg api: how to handle the max 1000 requests limit

Tags: programming, bloomberg, commodities

I am using the Bloomberg API in R (package Rblpapi) to find the nearby price at elevator locations for Soybean/Corn in given states in the US. I use the function [lookupSecurity](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Rblpapi/versions/0.3.6/topics/lookupSecurity):

`library(Rblpapi)
blpConnect()
lookupSecurity("CRNYUSOH", yellowkey="indx", maxResults=1000)`

The problem is that there is a maximum of 1000 results returned, which seems to originate from the API, not from R. Now I hit this limit for many states, mainly because it returns sometimes multiple maturities per location, while I am only interested in one single maturity.

I get for example *duplicates* like:

- CRNYUSAL AAAA xxx CGB
- CRNYUSAL AAAA xxy CGB
- CRNYUSAL AAAA xxz CGB

where xxx, xxy and xxz stand for different matirities, while I am only interested in one single maturity.

How can I handle this case? I would like to search for terms without the xxx, but it seems the API is not allowing to do a search with regular expressions? Any other solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing `maxResults=1000` to a higher number?

Comment: Yes, I did! But ineffective... as the documentation of the function says:  *appears to be capped at 1000*.

Comment: HELP HELP should be able to help. If you get an answer you can post it here for future visitors.